# How can I only count cells if a different cell is a specific value?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a range of cells that have different numbers. Each cell has another cell next to it which can contain OPEN or CLOSED. I only want to SUM the cells if their status cell says OPEN.

Here's an example of what the number and status looks like

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust for your own columns and ranges:

**=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B10="OPEN")*(A2:A10))**

You could also use SUMIF() or SUMIFS().

Answer (score 1):

`SUMIF` is normally preferable for summing with a condition

`=SUMIF(B:B,"Open",A:A)`